# Erro ao fazer um loop para comentários no instagram, alg me ajuda? Python Selenium

Tags: python, loop, selenium-webdriver, instagram-api

Eu preciso fazer um loop que pegue linha por linha de um arquivo .txt e poste como comentário no instagram. Através de um teste eu consegui imprimir as 10 primeiras linhas de um arquivo .txt

```
arquivo = open('UsersFinal.txt', 'r')
linha = 0
while linha <= 10:
    print(arquivo.readline())
    linha = linha + 1
print('FIM')
arquivo.close
```

Porém quando eu fui tentar comentar ele só comentava a primeira linha e depois parava. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Uma parte do código:

```
arquivo = open('teste.txt', 'r')
linha = 0
while linha <= 4:
    commentArea = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
    commentArea.click()
    time.sleep(4)
    commentArea = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
    commentArea.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    commentArea.send_keys(arquivo.readline())
    time.sleep(1)
    publicar_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     ']")
    publicar_button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    linha = linha + 1
print('FIM!')
arquivo.close
```

Comment: nesse seu txt ele só tem os nomes que vão ser citados na postagem? Exemplo:
\@usuario1
\@usuario2

Comment: Sim. Mas ontem eu fiquei tentando uns jeitos e ao invés de pegar as linhas do arquivo, eu coloquei tudo em uma lista e ai funcionou.

Comment: Eu ia te sugerir isso, pois eu já fiz num projeto e foi a melhor coisa, passar para uma lista, outra coisa, você pode reduzir seu código ali, você está pedindo para ele clicar duas vezes no campo "('Ypffh')" e para o botão você pode usar o xpath ```driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()```

Answer (score -1):

Então, não sei como resolver seu problema, mas se você comentar varias vezes por esse método no instagram ele vai perceber que você é na verdade um bot e te proibir de comentar, o caminho correto é simular ao máximo uma pessoa humana digitando.

Tenta isso depois.

```
for letra in arquivo.readline():
    commentArea.send_keys(letra)
    time.sleep(random.randint(3,8)/25)
```

Eu ja fiz um bot de comentários pro instagram usando selenium, no meu programa eu armazenei o nome dos usuarios em uma lista e depois num arquivo txt. Depois disso o programa sorteava três perfis dessa lista e comentava letra por letra.

Comment: Ontem eu fiquei tentando uns jeitos e ao invés de pegar as linhas do arquivo, eu coloquei tudo em uma lista e ai funcionou. Obg pela dica de simular ao máximo uma pessoa digitando.

Answer (score -2):

O problema pode ser que o método `readline()` lê uma linha de cada vez e avança para a próxima linha a cada chamada, então quando você chama o método novamente na próxima iteração do loop, ele lê a próxima linha e avança novamente, e assim por diante. Isso significa que seu código está lendo apenas uma linha por iteração e comentando apenas essa linha.
Uma solução seria armazenar todas as linhas do arquivo em uma lista e, em seguida, iterar sobre essa lista para comentar cada linha. Você pode fazer isso usando o método `readlines()` em vez de `readline():`

```
arquivo = open('teste.txt', 'r')
linhas = arquivo.readlines()
arquivo.close()

for linha in linhas:
    commentArea = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
    commentArea.click()
    time.sleep(4)
    commentArea = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
    commentArea.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    commentArea.send_keys(linha)
    time.sleep(1)
    publicar_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     ']")
    publicar_button.click()
    time.sleep(5)

print('FIM!')
```

Dessa forma, o código lê todas as linhas do arquivo e as armazena em uma lista chamada `linhas`. Em seguida, o `loop` for itera sobre essa lista e comenta cada linha no Instagram.